# Trying to figure out recursive basics

Tags: java, if-statement, recursion, methods

Would really really love if someone could explain to me how this code I wrote is not even close to what I thought it would produce. I wrote the code trying to prove that `int n` was going to be `n = 4` and so In my head and on paper I thought my results in step by step would be as followed:

1. 4 * 4 + (3) = 19
2. 3 * 3 + (2) = 11
3. 2 * 2 + (1) = 5
4. 1 * 1 + (0) = 1
5. return 0

   Can someone tell me why it is not that? and walk me through the recursive steps?

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

            int n;
            System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
            n = kbd.nextInt();

           System.out.println("recursive value "+intValue(n));
      }
      public static int intValue(int n)
      {
            int total;
            int x;
           if(n == 0)
              return 0;
           else 
             total = n * n + intValue(n-1);
             System.out.println("Recursive total: "+total);
             return total;
     }
   ```

Comment: You can walk through it yourself by using a debugger.

Comment: Your IDE should have a "Debug" mode, which will allow you to single-step your code, line by line.

Comment: Make sure to add a breakpoint by clicking on the line where you want it to stop.

Comment: All it says is debug start

Comment: `1*1+0 = 1` by the way

Comment: Sorry typo. I mean all it says is debug start and finish the code works fine I was wondering if someone could walk through the recursion and tell me what they come up with

Comment: Your example assumes you're adding plain old `n-1` to the value of `n^2`, when in fact it's actually the value of `n^2 + f(n-1)`, which yields a different result. See posted answers to see why it's not what you think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the recursive steps, starting with `n` being `4`:

```
intValue(4)
  n is not 0.  total is 4 * 4 + intValue(3)
  intValue(3)
    n is not 0.  total is 3 * 3 + intValue(2)
    intValue(2)
      n is not 0.  total is 2 * 2 + intValue(1)
      intValue(1)
        n is not 0.  total is 1 * 1 + intValue(0)
        intValue(0)
          n is 0, intValue(0) returns 0.
        1 * 1 + 0 = 1.
        Print Recursive value: 1, intValue(1) returns 1.
      2 * 2 + 1 = 5.
      Print Recursive value: 5, intValue(2) returns 5.
    3 * 3 + 5 = 14.
    Print Recursive value: 14, intValue(3) returns 14.
  4 * 4 + 14 = 30.
  Print Recursive value: 30, intValue(4) returns 30.
```

Back in main, the initial call returns `30`, and it prints `recursive value 30`.

The recursive call doesn't return `n - 1` itself to be added; it returns the result of calling `intValue` again with `n - 1` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

So your recursive equation is

```
total = n * n + intValue(n-1);
```

And when you run it with 4, it is

```
4 * 4 + intValue(3)
```

in which case **intValue(3)** is

```
3 * 3 + intValue(2)
```

in which case **intValue(2)** is

```
2 * 2 + intValue(1)
```

in which case **intValue(1)** is

```
1 * 1 + intValue(0)
```

in which case **intValue(0)** is

```
0
```

in which case going back, **intValue(1)** is

```
1 * 1 + intValue(0) = 1*1 + 0 = 1;
```

in which case going back, **intValue(2)** is

```
2 * 2 + intValue(1) = 2 * 2 + 1 = 5
```

in which case **intValue(3)** is

```
3 * 3 + intValue(2) = 3 * 3 + 5 = 14
```

in which case **intValue(4)** is

```
4 * 4 + intValue(3) = 4 * 4 + 14 = 30
```

Comment: Why once it goes all the way down to 0 wont it return 0? why would it do back up ?

Comment: @JeffGreenwood: Imagine you had 5 functions `intValueA`, `intValueB`, `intValueC`, etc. that each called the next one, rather than itself.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Because the value of `intValue(2)` results to be `5`, and the result of `intValue(3)` depends on `intValue(2)` which is `5`, for example. I tried to edit my post to make it clearer.

Comment: Yea just still getting used to recursion its kinda funky

Comment: Think of recursion like a stack... each time you make a recursive call, a new item is pushed onto the stack. When the base case is reached, each item is popped off the stack, which creates a return value for each subsequent item as it's popped off. This is the "going back up" you've asked about. Once the stack is empty, your function has completed.

Answer (score 0):

The thing about recursion is that it keeps calling itself until it hits the point n == 0 return. The way you have tried to work it out on paper is upside down.

It wont evaluate your equation until n == 0, and all the recursive calls are basically stacked waiting for the result. So it gets worked out like this, (where each op in the brackets is waiting for the result of the recursive call):

total = 4 * 4 + (3*3 + (2 * 2 + (1 * 1 + 0)))

To evaluate

 5. (Top of stack), n = 0, return 0 
 4. n = 1, 1 * 1 + 0, return 1
 3. n = 2, 2 * 2 + 1, return 5
 2. n = 3, 3 * 3 + 5, return 14
 1. n = 4, 4 * 4 + 14, return 30